# Wi-fi and Bluetooth stops after while

Tags: networking, bluetooth, 17.04, hardware

I'm currently facing some issues with my Wi-Fi and Bluetooth for some reason or another, this started today and since then I've rebooted the laptop 3 times. All three times after boot Wi-Fi works for a few minutes, just normal, and then the connection drops.

NetworkManager Notification:
[image]

I was checking around the internet before posting anything and in some other post someone recommended to run the following command: `dmesg | tail`, here's my output:

```
[ 2342.030339] Bluetooth: hci0 hardware error 0x0d
[ 2344.070067] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0xfc05 tx timeout
[ 2344.070068] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version information failed (-110)
[ 2344.078150] Bluetooth: hci0 hardware error 0x0d
[ 2346.117788] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version information failed (-110)
[ 2346.117806] Bluetooth: hci0 command tx timeout
[ 2346.126553] Bluetooth: hci0 hardware error 0x0d
[ 2348.165608] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0xfc05 tx timeout
[ 2348.165609] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version information failed (-110)
[ 2348.173684] Bluetooth: hci0 hardware error 0x0d
```

I had not faced this issue before, today is the first time that this has happened and I don't really have an internet cable in my space at work so using Wi-Fi is the only way I get access to the internal databases, if anyone can shed any light into what I should do to fix it, please let me know.
If there's any extra information I need to provide, please let me know how to get there, I am still on the newbie side of the OS.

I'm running Ubuntu 17.04 Zetsy, have not had the chance to update to 17.10 and I won't be able to at work. The laptop is a Dell Inspiron 15R 5537.

Driver information:

```
Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:0000]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

It does say that it's a hardware error, I don't really care for Bluetooth, I haven't used it once since I got the laptop, if there's any way I can get my Wi-Fi working even if it costs me the Bluetooth functionality I'm up for it.